# Django Templates: Wordwrap and indent block text

Tags: html, django, django-templates, indentation

I'm a bit compulsive about having clean, readable and perfectly indented HTML. With Django’s template engine I almost have been able to achieve this with the exception of block text, or rather HTML generated by TinyMCE through the admin panel. The closest I could get is using the wordwrap filter; however this tag does not take any arguments to add an indentation to the new line. Is there any other way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your only option would be to [create your own filter](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/).

Django's `django.template.defaultfilters.wordwrap` uses the `django.utils.text.wrap` method to wrap text. You could look at that and modify the output in any way you want.

But it looks like a lot of work for having slightly more readable HTML. Sometimes good enough, is...

Comment: Ah, alright - yeah that is more trouble than its worth, but I just wanted to make sure I wasn't overlooking wordwrap or a similar filter. Thanks